# Return a string (for success or exception details) with PostJsonAsync - .NET Core REST API

Tags: c#, json, rest, blazor, dotnet-httpclient

I want my REST API to return a string with the exception details to the client. My client-side code is:

```
public async Task CreateUnit(UnitEntity unit)
    {
        try
        {
            var response = await _http.PostJsonAsync<HttpResponseMessage>("api/units", unit);
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //todo want to display error from the service and carry on
            //throw;
        }
    }
```

And the code for the service / API is:

```
[HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage CreateUnit(UnitEntity unit)
    {
        try
        {
            Dal.CreateUnit(unit);
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
            response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Created;
            response.Content = new StringContent($"The unit {unit.UnitName} was created successfully");
            return response;

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //todo send error message in Http response if possible
            //throw;
            return new HttpResponseMessage() {StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, Content = new StringContent(e.Message)};
        }
    }
```

I've tried just returning a string and it basically says that the JSON serialiser can't deserialise it (because it's already a raw string and not JSON). The code above throws an exception:

> Deserialization of reference types without parameterless constructor is not supported. Type 'System.Net.Http.HttpContent'

Comment: It's not possible with `PostJsonAsync` extension, you should use the `PostAsync` method, serialize the content and deserialize the response by yourself

Comment: Using this, I always end up with a 415 Unsupported Media Type, but the JSON is correct. Am I right in sending _http.PostAsync("api/units", new StringContent(unitJson)); ?

Comment: Nope : `_http.PostAsync("api/units", new StringContent(unitJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));`

Comment: Thanks, it's sending now, but the HttpResponseMessage is always 200. I've tried returning ActionResult<HttpResponseMessage> but that doesn't work either

Comment: Do u solved it ?

Comment: Sorry Diego, didn't manage it. I'll update here if I work on it again